# Android layout controlling table heights and widths of elements contained

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I have the following Android layout defined...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px">
    <TableLayout
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
        <TableRow
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px">
            <TextView
                p1:text="Small Text"
                p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                p1:layout_column="0"
                p1:id="@+id/textView1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px">
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px">
            <Button
                p1:text="Button"
                p1:layout_column="0"
                p1:id="@+id/button1"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="50dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Which results in...

[image]

Here is what I need it to do...

1. The TextView in row 1 needs a static height of 100dp.
2. The Button in row 3 needs a static height of 100dp.
3. Row 2 should take up the rest of available vertical space.
4. The TextView and Button should take up the entire client width (whatever device that is one)

How would I change the layout xml to accomplish this?

Comment: Try Textview height with 100dp and gravity set to top.  button with gravity bottom and row 2 match parents. All goes in one linearylayout that is oriented vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want table and rows so I provide you other solution which is which RelativeLayout and according to android documentation is best container to use.

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="text"
        android:background="#f0f" />
  <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:background="#0ff"  
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_above="@+id/button"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <!--put whenever you want in here-->

  </LinearLayout>
  <Button
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="button"
        android:background="#ff0"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]